# Store output from one command and process it for another

Tags: bash, text-processing, grep

I am working on Unix command line. I have two files. I want to `cat file1.txt` and `grep` the output in `file2.txt`

File1.txt

```
123A
223A
143A
153A
183A
123J
123P
```

File2.txt:

```
123A (TYU)
223A (RUT)
143A (EWRW) 4
153A (TGBW) 89 ()
183A (23) YHYT 
123J ikik 780
123P haja 123
XRQE haja 123
XRQE haja 909
```

The last 2 lines of `file2.txt` are not present in `file1.txt`

I am trying to do something like:

`head file1.txt | **and ??**` `grep file2.txt`

I tried with `xargs`, `$variable` to store it, but shell hangs or doesn't work.

Expected Output: *Edited*:

`123A (TYU)
223A (RUT)
143A (EWRW) 4
153A (TGBW) 89 ()
183A (23) YHYT 
123J ikik 780
123P haja 123`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the expected output.

Comment: Why doesn't your expected output include `123A (TYU)`?

Comment: @G-MAN Edited now. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to search for strings that are present in `file2.txt` using the strings from `file1.txt`?

If so you can use `grep`'s `-f` switch to accomplish this.

*excerpt from grep's man page*

> ```
>   -f FILE, --file=FILE
> ```
>
> Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero 
>   patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is specified by POSIX.)

So try the following:

```
$ grep -f file1.txt file2.txt 
123A (TYU)
223A (RUT)
143A (EWRW) 4
153A (TGBW) 89 ()
183A (23) YHYT 
123J ikik 780
123P haja 123
```

#### Passing a portion of file1.txt

If on the other hand you'd like to only search for a portion of the strings present in `file1.txt` you could use [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) to dynamically generate a subset of `file1.txt` and pass that as a temporary file to `grep`'s `-f` switch.

**For example:**

```
$ grep -f <(head -5 file1.txt) file2.txt 
123A (TYU)
223A (RUT)
143A (EWRW) 4
153A (TGBW) 89 ()
183A (23) YHYT
```

This will take the first 5 lines from `file1.txt` and pass them in as a temprary file via the `<(..)` notation to `grep`.